# Set blob properties when using Blob linked Service in Data Factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

CONTENT-TYPE when sinking blobs through the Blob Linked Service is always application/octet-stream. Can blob properties be set during a Copy Data task? If the underlying Linked Service uses the REST API endpoint then headers should be exposed. Only way to circumvent is to generate a Bearer token (see [sample](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-retrieve-token-from-azure-ad-using-oauth-2-0-9a3ed3f55013)) then issue a REST call after each Copy.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Campbell , can you provide more information. What did you tried and expecting?

Comment: To send along a key/value pair via the Blob Linked service to Azure Blob Storage as a property on the Blob. With the Azure Storage REST API this works.

Comment: Have a workaround using the Blob REST API to set properties but it would have been more "smooth" doing everything through the Blob DataSet + Linked Service.